# Get response header

Tags: r, rcurl, httr

I would like to get response headers from GET or POST.

My example is:

```
    library(httr)
    library(RCurl)
    url<-'http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/philosophy.html'
    doc<-GET(url)
    names(doc)

[1] "url"         "handle"      "status_code" "headers"     "cookies"     "content"     "times"       "config"
```

but there is no response headers, only request headers.

Result shoud be something like this:

```
Connection:Keep-Alive
Date:Mon, 11 Feb 2013 20:21:56 GMT
ETag:"126a001-e33d-4c12cf2702440"
Keep-Alive:timeout=15, max=100
Server:Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)
Vary:Accept-Encoding
```

Can I do this with R and httr/RCurl packages or R is not enough for this kind of problem?

**Edit**: I would like to get all response headers. I am mainly interested in **Location** response which is not in this example.

**Edit2**: I forgot to tell the system which I work on - it is Windows 7

My session.info

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Polish_Poland.1250  LC_CTYPE=Polish_Poland.1250    LC_MONETARY=Polish_Poland.1250
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                   LC_TIME=Polish_Poland.1250    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] rjson_0.2.12 RCurl_1.95-3 bitops_1.0-5 httr_0.2     XML_3.95-0.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] digest_0.6.2  stringr_0.6.2 tools_2.15.2
```

Comment: How do you know what the response should look like?

Comment: I would like to get Connection or from other link, Location.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it this way :

```
h <- basicHeaderGatherer()
doc <- getURI("http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/index.html", headerfunction = h$update)
h$value()
```

Which will give you a named vector :

```
                            Date                           Server 
 "Mon, 11 Feb 2013 20:41:58 GMT"         "Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu)" 
                   Last-Modified                             ETag 
 "Wed, 24 Oct 2012 15:49:35 GMT" "\"3262089-10bf-4ccd0088461c0\"" 
                   Accept-Ranges                   Content-Length 
                         "bytes"                           "4287" 
                            Vary                     Content-Type 
               "Accept-Encoding"                      "text/html" 
                          status                    statusMessage 
                           "200"                             "OK"
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to necro, but you can do this using httr, but `names()` on a response object from `httr::GET()` doesn't reveal them.

You can either use `httr::GET()` or `httr::HEAD()`, the difference being that `GET()` will also retrieve the object at the URI. So `HEAD()` is a more polite call to the server if you only want to check headers.

For example:

```
str(httr::HEAD("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820286/get-response-header"))
#> List of 10
#>  $ url        : chr "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820286/get-response-header"
#>  $ status_code: int 200
#>  $ headers    :List of 19
#>   ..$ connection               : chr "keep-alive"
#>   ..$ cache-control            : chr "private"
#>   ..$ content-type             : chr "text/html; charset=utf-8"
#>   ..$ content-encoding         : chr "gzip"
#>   ..$ strict-transport-security: chr "max-age=15552000"
#>   ..$ x-frame-options          : chr "SAMEORIGIN"
#>   ..$ x-request-guid           : chr "1ce6cb52-2fd2-43b4-ac62-a577e2554f8e"
#>   ..$ feature-policy           : chr "microphone 'none'; speaker 'none'"
#>   ..$ content-security-policy  : chr "upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' https://stackexchange.com"
#>   ..$ accept-ranges            : chr "bytes"
#>   ..$ date                     : chr "Fri, 15 Apr 2022 19:25:01 GMT"
#>   ..$ via                      : chr "1.1 varnish"
#>   ..$ x-served-by              : chr "cache-lga21933-LGA"
#>   ..$ x-cache                  : chr "MISS"
#>   ..$ x-cache-hits             : chr "0"
#>   ..$ x-timer                  : chr "S1650050702.976391,VS0,VE11"
#>   ..$ vary                     : chr "Accept-Encoding,Fastly-SSL"
#>   ..$ x-dns-prefetch-control   : chr "off"
#>   ..$ set-cookie               : chr "prov=86c2b2fb-5e39-9798-60ba-0f65eee27a7c; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly"
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "insensitive" "list"
#>  $ all_headers:List of 1
#>   ..$ :List of 3
#>   .. ..$ status : int 200
#>   .. ..$ version: chr "HTTP/1.1"
#>   .. ..$ headers:List of 19
#>   .. .. ..$ connection               : chr "keep-alive"
#>   .. .. ..$ cache-control            : chr "private"
#>   .. .. ..$ content-type             : chr "text/html; charset=utf-8"
#>   .. .. ..$ content-encoding         : chr "gzip"
#>   .. .. ..$ strict-transport-security: chr "max-age=15552000"
#>   .. .. ..$ x-frame-options          : chr "SAMEORIGIN"
#>   .. .. ..$ x-request-guid           : chr "1ce6cb52-2fd2-43b4-ac62-a577e2554f8e"
#>   .. .. ..$ feature-policy           : chr "microphone 'none'; speaker 'none'"
#>   .. .. ..$ content-security-policy  : chr "upgrade-insecure-requests; frame-ancestors 'self' https://stackexchange.com"
#>   .. .. ..$ accept-ranges            : chr "bytes"
#>   .. .. ..$ date                     : chr "Fri, 15 Apr 2022 19:25:01 GMT"
#>   .. .. ..$ via                      : chr "1.1 varnish"
#>   .. .. ..$ x-served-by              : chr "cache-lga21933-LGA"
#>   .. .. ..$ x-cache                  : chr "MISS"
#>   .. .. ..$ x-cache-hits             : chr "0"
#>   .. .. ..$ x-timer                  : chr "S1650050702.976391,VS0,VE11"
#>   .. .. ..$ vary                     : chr "Accept-Encoding,Fastly-SSL"
#>   .. .. ..$ x-dns-prefetch-control   : chr "off"
#>   .. .. ..$ set-cookie               : chr "prov=86c2b2fb-5e39-9798-60ba-0f65eee27a7c; domain=.stackoverflow.com; expires=Fri, 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly"
#>   .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "insensitive" "list"
#>  $ cookies    :'data.frame': 1 obs. of  7 variables:
#>   ..$ domain    : chr "#HttpOnly_.stackoverflow.com"
#>   ..$ flag      : logi TRUE
#>   ..$ path      : chr "/"
#>   ..$ secure    : logi FALSE
#>   ..$ expiration: POSIXct[1:1], format: "2054-12-31 18:00:00"
#>   ..$ name      : chr "prov"
#>   ..$ value     : chr "86c2b2fb-5e39-9798-60ba-0f65eee27a7c"
#>  $ content    : raw(0) 
#>  $ date       : POSIXct[1:1], format: "2022-04-15 19:25:01"
#>  $ times      : Named num [1:6] 0 0.0471 0.1203 0.2368 0.2819 ...
#>   ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6] "redirect" "namelookup" "connect" "pretransfer" ...
#>  $ request    :List of 7
#>   ..$ method    : chr "HEAD"
#>   ..$ url       : chr "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14820286/get-response-header"
#>   ..$ headers   : Named chr "application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*"
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "Accept"
#>   ..$ fields    : NULL
#>   ..$ options   :List of 3
#>   .. ..$ useragent    : chr "libcurl/7.64.1 r-curl/4.3 httr/1.4.2"
#>   .. ..$ nobody       : logi TRUE
#>   .. ..$ customrequest: chr "HEAD"
#>   ..$ auth_token: NULL
#>   ..$ output    : list()
#>   .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "write_memory" "write_function"
#>   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "request"
#>  $ handle     :Class 'curl_handle' <externalptr> 
#>  - attr(*, "class")= chr "response"
Created on 2022-04-15 by the reprex package (v2.0.0)
```

Answer (score -1):

curl -I http://www.google.com

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Mon, 11 Feb 2013 20:36:06 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=ec3eb1b4b4f31100:FF=0:TM=1360614966:LM=1360614966:S=EjQCjjdv07A6PRtw; expires=Wed, 11-Feb-2015 20:36:06 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com
Set-Cookie: NID=67=neiRZQ9fctd6NqzdKNdRMzfBqk-yAaxxxruYrnsvTcJeG7q8TJm5Ybv1UZ2ZV_ZheYhy-RwgAppHUh1VhIz4KOcFbcl8-0DvtPYXxaiSQmYvXGEKqeh4glhqvhOdxJKB; expires=Tue, 13-Aug-2013 20:36:06 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See http://www.google.com/support/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=151657 for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

curl -v http://google.com/

```
$ curl -v http://google.com/
* About to connect() to google.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 66.102.7.104... connected
* Connected to google.com (66.102.7.104) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.16.4 (i386-apple-darwin9.0) libcurl/7.16.4 OpenSSL/0.9.7l zlib/1.2.3
> Host: google.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Location: http://www.google.com/
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Thu, 15 Jul 2010 06:06:52 GMT
< Expires: Sat, 14 Aug 2010 06:06:52 GMT
< Cache-Control: public, max-age=2592000
< Server: gws
< Content-Length: 219
< X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
< 
<HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
<TITLE>301 Moved</TITLE></HEAD><BODY>
<H1>301 Moved</H1>
The document has moved
<A HREF="http://www.google.com/">here</A>.
</BODY></HTML>
* Connection #0 to host google.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: after having downloaded and installed cURL exe, you might use it like this ``system("curl -I http://www.google.com")`` or maybe like this ``shell("curl -I http://www.google.com")`` :-)

Comment: @Maciej  To install `curl`, as petermeissner suggests, you might also need to install Msys or MinGW. A simple way to get this all set up (including curl) is to install [git](https://git-scm.com/downloads), which includes curl in its "Git bash" shell. As a plus, git is a respectable source control system!