# curl download file only if server file date modified later than local file in R

Tags: r, curl

Looking at {targets} package for managing some relatively simple pipelines which download data and create some charts before using it for more complex projects.

In order to reduce pipeline time, I would like to download data files from a web server only if the files on the server have a date modified stamp which is *later* than the version already present locally; if they don't exist locally then I would like them to be downloaded.

This works in the shell using the `-R` flag to set the local copy to have same date modified as the file on the server after successful download and the `-z` flag sets up the time condition to match against the local file and only download of server copy is more recent.

This bash code block sets the local copy modified date to later than the server copy to prove it doesn't redownload:

```bash
curl -R https://files.digital.nhs.uk/9B/DF836C/hosp-epis-stat-admi-hosp-prov-2022-23-tab_v2.xlsx -z test.xlsx -o test.xlsx

touch -d '2023-01-01T00:00:00' test.xlsx

curl -R https://files.digital.nhs.uk/9B/DF836C/hosp-epis-stat-admi-hosp-prov-2022-23-tab_v2.xlsx -z test.xlsx -o test.xlsx
```

Setting the local copy modified date to earlier than server copy does initiate a download.

Trying to recreate this in `R` seems to be proving a little difficult.

Finding it difficult to understand how to pass this extra argument to `curl`. This is what I have so far as a test script in `R`:

```r
# trying to set up curl with timecondition
h <- curl::new_handle()
curl::handle_setopt(h, timecondition = 1)

# download 
curl::multi_download(
  urls = "https://files.digital.nhs.uk/9B/DF836C/hosp-epis-stat-admi-hosp-prov-2022-23-tab_v2.xlsx", 
  destfile = basename("https://files.digital.nhs.uk/9B/DF836C/hosp-epis-stat-admi-hosp-prov-2022-23-tab_v2.xlsx"),
  h
  )

# set the local file modified date to later than the server file modified date to prove it doesn't download if local copy date is later
Sys.setFileTime("hosp-epis-stat-admi-hosp-prov-2022-23-tab_v2.xlsx", "2030-01-01")

curl::multi_download(
  urls = "https://files.digital.nhs.uk/9B/DF836C/hosp-epis-stat-admi-hosp-prov-2022-23-tab_v2.xlsx", 
  destfile = basename("https://files.digital.nhs.uk/9B/DF836C/hosp-epis-stat-admi-hosp-prov-2022-23-tab_v2.xlsx"),
  h
  )
```

Looking at the libcurl documents https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_TIMECONDITION.html there is an argument called CURLOPT_TIMECOND_IFMODSINCE within the library documents which I am guessing I am trying to access via R but can't work out how.

Any thoughts on how to access additional arguments for curl which are not available directly with `curl::multi_download()` or another approach most welcome.

Thanks

Comment: Not direct answer, but please have a look on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2313620/is-it-possible-to-retrieve-the-last-modified-date-of-a-file-using-javascript and play with Last-Modified header like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20839237/r-how-to-cleanly-retrieve-the-attributes-of-a-remote-file-on-the-internet

Answer (score 0):

There are two options you need to set. In `libcurl` world, these are `CURLOPT_TIMECONDITION` and `CURLOPT_TIMEVALUE`. In `R` world, these are `timecondition` and `timevalue`. The first tells `curl` there is a condition to compare against (i.e., it's a flag). The second option tells the actual value to compare against.

`CURLOPT_TIMECOND_IFMODSINCE` is a enum which when using R, you have to look up with `curl_symbols("TIMECOND_IFMODSINCE")`. (You seem to have this part as the value is `1`, but stating this in case it's not clear to others).

Setting `timevalue = 1` is the first step. Now you just have to set the `timevalue` to the last modified date of the local file.

The last piece to this is how you are setting the options. When using `curl::multi_download`, in your original code you are passing a `handle` to the `...` arguments.  `multi_download` may need to create multiple new `handle`s, so the  `...` is used to pass the options.

Skip defining `h`. Adding a little refactoring, your download call should be:

```
destURL <-"https://files.digital.nhs.uk/9B/DF836C/hosp-epis-stat-admi-hosp-prov-2022-23-tab_v2.xlsx" 
localDest <- basename(destURL)

curl::multi_download(
  urls = destURL, 
  destfile = localDest,
  timecondition = 1, 
  timevalue = as.numeric(file.info(localDest)$mtime)
)
```

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense now you've shown/explained it. However it doesn't quite seem to be the same as bash `curl -z`. If there is no local copy of the file then an `NA` is returned from `file.info()` and curl then fails. I guess I could include an `if` statement to check if file present and download if not but in bash `curl` seems to be able to do this natively unless I have misunderstood